# jQuery each elements, but only first parents?

Tags: jquery, each

Is there a way to select only the top parents in a div?

My structure:

```
<div class="topParent">
    +<div class="child">
        -<div class="child">
            -<div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    +<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I've added the + and - signs to indicate what I'm trying to get. I'm using `$('.topParent').find('.child').each(function() { .. } );` to iterate, but I get all .child elements selected in the loop.

Is there a way to select only the top .child elements, and then go through them and count how many other .child elements that particular div has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.topParent > .child').each(function() {...});
```

selects only direct children !

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.topParent').children('.child').each(function() { .. } );
```

Comment: Had to delete my answer because you answered 25 seconds earlier than me :P